# Persistent Collection View Cell Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

please bear with me as I am new to swift programming.

I have a `myCollectionViewController` that is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`. The cells for the `MyCollectionViewController` are a class of `MyCollectionViewCell`, which is a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

What I am trying to do is change the background of the `MyCollectionViewCell` based on the user selection AND have this selection persist when the user scrolls to other cells of the `MyCollectionViewController`. I have tried two ways to do this, and so far both have failed.

The first way was to write code in the `didSelectItemAt` method of the `MyCollectionViewController`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

However, this did not work and the cell colour was not changed.

The other way I tried to do this was by changing the `isSelected` property of the `MyCollectionViewCell`.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    // Change what happens when the user selects a cell

    didSet {

        if self.isSelected {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = Colours.primary

        } else {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = Colours.secondary

        }  
    }
}
```

Although this worked, the selection did not persist. That is when the user scrolled to a different cell in the `collectionView` and then scrolled back, the selection was gone.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use dequeue in `didSelectItemAt` as it'll return other cell than the clicked

```
var allInde = [IndexPath]()

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as!   MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    if !(allIndex.contains(indexPath)) {
        allInde.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

and in cellForItem check whether indexpath to show is in the array and color it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

       if allIndex.contains(indexPath) {
          cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Colours.primary
       }
       else {
          cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Colours.secondary
       }
  }
```

// se here updated code

[SPRAIN](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7ivp9bu4ncanw9h/SPRAIN-master.rar)

Comment: can you clarify how I can do the check in the last step?

Comment: The first is part (changing the colour when selected) is working. And although the colour is persisting, it is now changing the colour of other cells Any advice on how I can fix that?

Comment: if every cell will have a different color upon selecting then you have to keep the color with indexpath in the array but if they are only 2 colors then switch between them according to answer

Comment: Every cell can only have one of two colours. However, the issue is that the index path is the same for some of the cells (as I actually have a `NestedCollectionView` inside my 'MainCollectionView').

Comment: Would you be able to take a look at my source code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have marked this answer right as it solved my problem. DO you mind explaining what you did though?

Comment: @M.I I kept a global array to store selected indexPaths and constructed every string from it's collectionView tag which i set in cellForItem in the outer collection and the indexPath.row that was clicked to uniquely identify any row in any collection , in didDeselect i remove it from the array and when calling cellForItem in the nested collection i search for the indexPath.row to be shown in the array add it if it's not already there , and most important clear all item with the same collection.tag to ensure only one item selected at a time , i edited this project before , glad it helped

Comment: Yes you did! Thankyou. A follow up question though, if I would like for multiple selections to be possible, how could I do that?

Comment: you only need to remove the for loop in didSelectItem in the nested collection and ensure the item doesn't exists before appending it , note by this string construct is unique and you can parse it to find the answers that the user has selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170638/discussion-between-m-i-and-sh-khan).